# multiple testing with BH correction

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, biostatistics, fishers-exact-test

I want to do genome wide association study. I have about 1,500,000 SNPs, and 36 samples with 18 from tumor cells and 18 from normal lood cells. We make fisher test or chi square test(we admit fisher test in practice) for 1,500,000 SNPs simutaneously to test the association of SNP with this cancer, so we actually do multiple testing and use BH correction to control False discorvery rate. But we find that the corrected p value is at least 0.51, this is too large which means our false discovery rate should be set to be at least 0.51 so that there could be at least one significant SNP. I don't know if anyone has experience in biostatistics and what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The standard for nominal significance in GWAS study is 5x10E-8. This level is based in the effective number of independent SNPs taking into account the linkage disequilibrium structure in the whole genome.

The FDR correction is used when the number of significant tests is high, typical situation analysing genetic expression data. The problem with the FDR analysing SNPs is the majority of GWAS study the number of significant SNPs are very small.

Comment: thanks! so what is your suggestion here? Is my procedure correct here and if yes, does that mean we got no significant SNP? (we didn't have any p value around 5*10e-8 for any individual test, the minimal is about 10e-5 level)

Comment: The Fisher test is correct here, but maybe you has not power to detect significant differences with the sample size. You could try to use logistic regression with an additive model, defining a variable for each SNP with codes 0, 1 and 2, as the number of allele rare. These variables are included in the regression model as continuous.